# how to fetch database value and match it with user input value and display the match details only not other

Tags: php

I have a form where an employee can search details of a student based on their skills.
In the form I have select box where employee can select a skills like(java,php,android...). Once he selects a value, it will be matched with the multiple values stored in the database and displays only the record who's skill matches.

But I am getting unexpected output.

example :- Employee selects a skill as 'C'. Now there are two students in db and student A has following skills(C,java,php) and Student B has following skills(css,android,dotnet). So according to the input only student A should be displayed but I am getting both because student B has a value called 'css', here c is an starting alphabet.

Any idea how to avoid this. I have used following query in php to get the result. Please help me to solve this.

```
$skl = implode(",",$_REQUEST['serskil']);   
$qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stdreg WHERE skills LIKE '%$skl%'");
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you have a specific set of skills in a form from where the employee can select the specific skills he wants, I don't think you need to do any pattern-matching here. May be just take care of the commas if there are multiple skills.

Comment: Can you paste a test data of `$_REQUEST['serskil']` ?

Comment: No we need because while student is doing registration he might select multiple skills and this skills are stored in db .... Now if employee wants to search as the students having c skill he should get all the values that has c in is row so ....pleaez help me out

Comment: user007 :- it is requesting the value from url...it is getting the value from html form when i click submit

Comment: So what's one of the values sent?

Comment: As iam sending c it displays the column that has css ...i think it is matching only the first alphabet of the word as c and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$skl = $_REQUEST['serskil'];
SELECT * FROM stdreg WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$skl', skills)>0;
```

### Alternate:

```
$skl = $_REQUEST['serskil'];
SELECT * FROM stdreg WHERE skills like '%,$skl' or skills like '$skl,%' or skills like '%,$skl,%';
```

**[Reference on FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)**

EDIT: Atually you dont need the `implode()` for this code. Sorry I missed to specify.

Comment: I guess you have **comma separated values** as `C,java,php` in the column `skills`. Am I right?

Comment: yes....but your code shows me different output...when i use '%,$skl' and search as java it displayes nothing

Comment: If it's **comma separated values** in a single row then `FIND_IN_SET()` mysql function is the best.

Comment: @RohitDubey Atually you dont need the `implode()` for this code. Sorry I missed to specify. Try any one now.

Comment: If you are passing only one value and not an array then why would you need implode?

Comment: You are selecting only one value from the drop down??? FIND_IN_SET() should work in such situations.

Comment: no sir .. it depends on employee if he want he can search multiple value which is working but when he selects a value like c and if a student column has skills such as java,php,css then according to employee this must not be displayed but it is displayed ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$skl = preg_split("/','/", $_REQUEST['serskil']);
$qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stdreg WHERE skills LIKE '$skl'");
```

this will search the exact string.

Comment: no ... now it shows the record only when all the values in db are exactly same as the input

Comment: try this..i am not sure if it is correct $skl = preg_split("/','/", $_REQUEST['serskil']);

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure isn't normalized well. Ideally, you would need a table like (let's say `skill_table`):

```
skill_id | skill_name
--------- -----------
   1     |    C
   2     |    java
   3     |    php
```

Another table, let's say `student_skill` that matches student's skills with the above table like:

```
student_id  | skill_id
----------    --------
   S1       |    1      //Student s1 has skill C
   S1       |    2     //Student s1 has skill java
   S1       |    3    //Student s1 has skill php
   S2       |    1
```

And with this all you would need to do is:

```
$skl = $_REQUEST['serskil'];
$qr = mysql_query("SELECT student_id FROM student_skill WHERE skill_id=(SELECT skill_id from skill_table where skill_name='".$skl."')"); 

//If `$_REQUEST['serskil']` is C, this query will output `S1`,`S2`
```

Comment: my database has the value like this                                            student_id s1 has skilss as 1,2,3,4,5                                 and if employee is searching for skill 1 then this should be displayed....but this is not my problem

Comment: @user007 True, but the OP may not be the designer of the DATABASE and hence the DATABASE schema is not always in the hand of the programmer. Now its smart to design a code to implement the need on the given resources rather than dissecting the resources itself. Hence your suggestion is simply not the required solution.

Comment: @RajeshPaul I see. Then, indeed you are smart and I am not.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this approach.

First, you should normalize your database to the best level as possible. In your case, lets create a table called 'student':

```
CREATE TABLE student (student_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL, last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL);
```

Then a table called 'skill':

```
CREATE TABLE skill (skill_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, skill_name varchar(10) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

And lastly a table called 'students_skill':

```
CREATE TABLE students_skill (students_skill_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, student int NOT NULL, skill int NOT NULL);
```

The last table will store the combination for the student with their skill, this relationship is one-is-to-many. The column `student` and `skill` on the table `student_skill` are foreign keys.

We then add indexes to our foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `students_skill` ADD INDEX( `student`, `skill`);
```

We will also add a `UNIQUE` value for BOTH `student` and `skill` to avoid duplicate issue when entering the same student with the same skill:

```
ALTER TABLE `students_skill` ADD UNIQUE( `student`, `skill`);
```

And finally, add the foreign key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE students_skill ADD CONSTRAINT fk_student FOREIGN KEY (student) references student (student_id);
ALTER TABLE students_skill ADD CONSTRAINT fk_skill FOREIGN KEY (skill) references skill (skill_id);
```

Now, lets assume we had this value on our table:

```
Table student (student_id = first_name, last_name)
1 = Kiel, Labuca
2 = Labuca, Kiel

Table skill (skill_id = skill_name)
1 = php
2 = css
3 = html
4 = c

Table students_skill (student_skill_id = student / skill)
1 = 1 / 2 (Kiel, Labuca / css)
2 = 1 / 3 (Kiel, Labuca / html)
3 = 2 / 1 (Labuca, Kiel / php)
4 = 2 / 4 (Labuca, Kiel / c)
```

Now if we want to select the student which skill has C programming language, here is our query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(student.last_name, ', ', student.first_name) AS 'name' FROM student, skill, students_skill WHERE student.student_id = students_skill.student AND skill.skill_id = students_skill.skill AND skill.skill_name = 'C';
```

The query above will output only student `Labuca, Kiel` because he is the only `student` with the skill `C`.

And if you want to display it in a table using `HTML` here is the code:

```
<?php
    $resultSet = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(student.last_name, ', ', student.first_name) AS 'name' FROM student, skill, students_skill WHERE student.student_id = students_skill.student AND skill.skill_id = students_skill.skill AND skill.skill_name = 'C'");
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Student Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultSet)){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Just try to experiment different variants of query condition. The output you desire will depend on your query conditions. Good luck and happy coding.